# Laserprinter to print codes recognizable by tiptoi

Tags: printer

Ravensbuger sells [tiptoi books](https://www.ravensburger.de/shop/grosse-marken/tiptoi/index.html) which have almost invisible codes that can be read by a digital pen, which then makes sounds if you have uploaded the appropriate sounds to the pen before. The format of the codes as well as the file format for the pen [have been reverse engineered](https://github.com/entropia/tip-toi-reveng) and it's now possible to create own games etc.

Unfortunately the quality of my laser printer is not good enough for the pen to recognize the codes.

So I am now looking for a printer which can be used to print tiptoi compatible pages. From the last [Make magazine](http://make-magazin.de/), the requirement is just 1200 dpi, but I don't want to just buy any 1200 dpi printer. If someone could suggest a printer *and* has successfully printed tiptoi codes, that would be great.

The printer should

- print DIN A4
- be black and white only (no color needed)
- print in 1200 dpi or higher
- cost less than 200 € / 220 USD
- work with Windows (Linux support welcome)
- have Ethernet connection